# How comes mSATA and SATA SSDs have pretty much the same capacity?

Tags: ssd, sata, msata

mSATA SSDs look much smaller than SATA SSDs. How comes mSATA and SATA SSDs have pretty much the same capacity? I.e. of of now [Samsung 850 EVO mSATA SSD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TGIVRYU) can't have more than 1 TB, just like the [Samsung 850 EVO SATA III Internal SSD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010QD6W9I) (even though the 2 TB is coming soon). Wouldn't it be possible to "stack" mSATA SSDs in a SATA SSD?

[image]

Comment: SATA and mSATA are just the SATA interfaces to the host machine... stacking wouldn't work because they'd still be separate disks with independent connections. Technology is getting smaller but the costs for yet smaller technology are higher...

Comment: @BigChris "the costs for yet smaller technology are higher" --> in the case of the Samsung 850 EVO 1, SATA SSD is only ~10% cheaper than mSATA SSD. By stacking I didn't mean simply juxtaposing them but also do some rewiring so that it appears as a single drive, as some hard drives do. I am aware that mSATA and SATA are interfaces: what surprises me is that "small" SSDs have a similar TB capacity than larger ones.

Comment: Remember SATA is point-to-point, so you can't daisy chain it like SCSI or IDE disks, meaning each disk has a 1-1 relationship to its port. The only exception to this is when a raid controller is used in conjunction, and the SATA bus allows multiport access.

Comment: Question posted on Quora: https://www.quora.com/How-comes-mSATA-and-SATA-SSDs-have-pretty-much-the-same-capacity since it got downvoted here.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like manufacturers are now starting to stack SSDs: [Samsung has figured out how to supersize solid state storage with a whopping 16TB SSD.](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2971268/storage/samsung-takes-worlds-largest-storage-drive-crown-with-16tb-ssd.html):

> The company announced a new 16TB SSD (formatted capacity, 15.36TB) at the 2015 Flash Memory Summit. The massive increase in density is thanks to the 48-layer 3D TLC NAND that [Samsung announced earlier this week](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/212108-samsung-announces-new-256-bit-3d-nand-stacked-48-layers-high).